# Android date query not working properly

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am creating an app in which I have to store date and time on certain time when gps location changes but. I am having trouble in retrieving data from SQLITE. I am using these two functions to get current date and time and store them in DataBase.

```
public static String getCurentDate() {
    Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
    return String.valueOf(calender.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/"
            + String.valueOf(calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) + "/"
            + String.valueOf(calender.get(Calendar.YEAR));
}

public static String getCurentTime() {
    Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
    String strHour = String.valueOf(calender.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    String strMinute = String.valueOf(calender.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    if (strMinute.length() == 1)
        strMinute = "0" + strMinute;
    return strHour + ":" + strMinute;
}
```

I am using these 3 functions to get data retrieved from DB.

```
public ArrayList<LocationItem> getLocationItemsByDateTime(String timeFrom,
            String timeTo, String dateFrom, String dateTo) throws Exception {
        Cursor cur;
        ArrayList<LocationItem> locationItems = new ArrayList<LocationItem>();
        try {
            openDB(true);
            cur = dBase.rawQuery("select * from "
                    + LocationItemTable.TABLE_NAME + " where "
                    + LocationItemTable.COL_TIME + " between '" + timeFrom
                    + "' and '" + timeTo + "' and "
                    + LocationItemTable.COL_DATE + " between '" + dateFrom
                    + "' and '" + dateTo + "'", null);
            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    locationItems
                            .add(new LocationItem(cur.getInt(0), new Gson()
                                    .fromJson(cur.getString(1), LatLng.class),
                                    cur.getString(2), cur.getString(3)));
                } while (cur.moveToNext());
            }
            cur.close();
            return locationItems;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            closeDB();
        }
    }

public ArrayList<LocationItem> getLocationItemsByTime(String timeFrom,
        String timeTo) throws Exception {
    Cursor cur;
    ArrayList<LocationItem> locationItems = new ArrayList<LocationItem>();
    try {
        openDB(true);
        cur = dBase.rawQuery("select * from "
                + LocationItemTable.TABLE_NAME + " where "
                + LocationItemTable.COL_TIME + " between '" + timeFrom
                + "' and '" + timeTo + "'", null);
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                locationItems
                        .add(new LocationItem(cur.getInt(0), new Gson()
                                .fromJson(cur.getString(1), LatLng.class),
                                cur.getString(2), cur.getString(3)));
            } while (cur.moveToNext());
        }
        cur.close();
        return locationItems;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        closeDB();
    }
}

public ArrayList<LocationItem> getLocationItemsByDate(String dateFrom,
        String dateTo) throws Exception {
    Cursor cur;
    ArrayList<LocationItem> locationItems = new ArrayList<LocationItem>();
    try {
        openDB(true);
        cur = dBase.rawQuery("select * from "
                + LocationItemTable.TABLE_NAME + " where "
                + LocationItemTable.COL_DATE + " between '" + dateFrom
                + "' and '" + dateTo + "'", null);
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                locationItems
                        .add(new LocationItem(cur.getInt(0), new Gson()
                                .fromJson(cur.getString(1), LatLng.class),
                                cur.getString(2), cur.getString(3)));
            } while (cur.moveToNext());
        }
        cur.close();
        return locationItems;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        closeDB();
    }
}
```

But on these queries are not working for all possibilities. Like if I enter time 10:00 to 20:00 it give results but if I enter 11:00 to 20:00 query returns null. Same case is for date

Comment: Show some example data.

Comment: I have data store of time 15:03 but it gives result when I select timeFrom and timeTo from 10:00 to 23:00 but query return null when I select from 1:00 to say 23:00 and same issue is with date. for some values of range it works for some are not.

Comment: I am giving date as same format as you told 2014-10-11 but still no change. It still works as same as previous format where I was using 11/10/2014.

Comment: `1:00` is not in `hh:mm` format. Two `h`s means `01`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are compared as strings, so `2/1/2000` is larger than `11/30/2014`.

To get correct comparisons, use formats like `yyyy-mm-dd` and `hh:mm:ss`.
(These also happen to be the formats supported by the [built-in date functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).)

Comment: I have tried above formats as yyyy-mm-dd and hh:mm. but no changes happen. still query works for some time and some time not. will the query also changes or just help me to use the date and time functions if you know.